# Capitalize all XML attribute names

Tags: regex, xml, vim, sed

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
 <DataDictionary numberOfFields="5">
  <DataField name="Species" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
   <Value value="setosa"/>
   <Value value="versicolor"/>
   <Value value="virginica"/>
  </DataField>
  <DataField name="Sepal.Length" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Sepal.Width" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Petal.Length" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Petal.Width" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
 </DataDictionary>
```

Can someone provide a regular expression (e.g. for vim or sed) that will capitalize all the attribute names?

For example, I would like `numberOfFields` to be `NumberOfFields` and `dataType` to be `DataType`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to handle XML with sed, since sed works in a line-based manner and XML does not really care about line breaks. For example, you could have

```
<foo bar=
   "baz"/>
```

in perfectly valid XML, which would be very difficult to handle with sed (or other plain-text tools).

I propose using an XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="capname"
                  select="concat(translate(substring(name(.),1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), substring(name(.), 2))"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$capname}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Put this in a file, say `foo.xsl`, then use an XSLT processor such as `xsltproc` to run it:

```
xsltproc foo.xsl foo.xml
```

where `foo.xml` is your XML file. Alternatively, with `xalan`:

```
xalan -xsl foo.xsl -in foo.xml
```

Any XSLT processor will do; for others, check their manpage.

This works as follows:

```
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

is the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) that applies to all nodes (not attributes in this case, because they're handled elsewhere) and recursively applies templates. This makes it so that the output of the transformation is a copy of the input where no other templates apply. The meat is in

```
  <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="capname"
                  select="concat(translate(substring(name(.),1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), substring(name(.), 2))"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="{$capname}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

This applies to all attributes (`@*`).

```
concat(translate(substring(name(.),1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), substring(name(.), 2))
```

is the capitalized version of the attribute name, and it is assigned to the variable `capname`. Then

```
<xsl:attribute name="{$capname}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

inserts a new attribute with that capitalized name and the old value in place of the old, non-capitalized attribute.

This will work with all valid XML input.

Comment: Thank you. This is a complete solution. Also, thanks for pointing me to xsltproc.

Answer (score 3):

Use proper XML handling tools, sed can't easily handle all the possible XML syntax rules.

With [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), an XML editing shell, for example:

```sh
open file.xml ;
rename { ucfirst } //@* ;
# OR, to avoid any Perl:
# rename xsh:ucfirst(name()) //@* ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Oh, that is quite nice. I'll have to take a closer look at xsh2.